# Как сделать размытие при наведении на картику?

Tags: css

```css
img:hover {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(pixelRadius=5);
  }
```

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUTExMWFhUXGBcbGBgYGBgaFxcYGBUeFxgYGBgaHSggGRolHRgYITEhJSkrLi4vFx8zODMtNygtLisBCgoKDg0OGhAQGy4lHyUtLS0tLS8tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLSstLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIALcBFAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAACAgMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAADBAIFAAEGBwj/xABAEAACAQMCAwYFAwIEAwgDAAABAhEAAyESMQRBUQUTImFxgQYykaGxQsHwUtEUI2LhJEPxBzNjcnOCkrKTorP/xAAZAQADAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAX/xAAkEQACAgICAgICAwAAAAAAAAAAAQIRAyESMUFRBBMyYRQicf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A8XSQ4kcxIpu/ZVHxDAb9R/vTvH8Daa+i2GchkQksADrK+KIJ8M7c6R4fF4aubQ08wTBmknZdUBghiV2B+3nVv2J2m1q5buIQGRpE7TsVaP0kSPekQ4DOLYJXIIPTaf7H0qHdFQr4IOD+4NNOhdqj334Y7S760Xe4CWu3FQQFIA8QSOZA+wq7CV4n8Gdsi3dtF821dWI5yqlQRmNYVj6gV7X2bxK3VZ1AgO6ggghgjadQ9YrrhPkjz82PiyaIBR4rB6Voj1qzAmtEt26ii1ImKBjKIKx1pdblGBNSBmit93UkNGWlYACY5VEUwUoeinYEIrAKIErTCgCFJ9rcQbdpnE+HTtv8wBAp01QfGvEaeFYc2IA+tAIuytDeluwuK73h7bzmIPqMU6bdMGLGTW9FMaIqDLRYC7ChlaZIobUwFWt1Du6YahsKBC1ylbtOXKWuCmMRuLS1xaedKXuJTEVt5ar79ura6tI3xVJgine1mso9xc1lUaHGdlcSD2hbuaVCyraVEIIyVUHYcvYUxd4W3xHEIluzobRdLeKS51uykiMQIEDpSNmyVCXEYeUZp7sR2TiVuEgEIwB8zJ+814so1td0ewn4ZR8GzWmZiCCUIBK+E6ogmRlTU7dmbS3SRBcgrMEkCZHXBrpOBsrxC3hevFdKcPbV2BbSCyAALvADEhRVPxXANaHDEklG8YMHEGDHWQB/JpxyW6fYnDyivUlCWE6SY/cehruPgr4p7p0DgFUW+UyQA9xRAMbKSkHfLA4rkzD94/hCi4BoBgMMldO+cH60O2O7If8AQzMB1GmMx7jHOtYyp2ZSipKmfTFplYYIJEBgDOlioaD0MMD71NUrzX4A+JYm25JEFhABZzpRFEnoFMZ2xyr0cGdjIrrjK0ebkxuDoI2KE8VKa2LM86ogChzTi3agLfSt6etIYVbk0YP50BQK2aTEMVlAU0RTUjJVAiiaJrClFiBRXD/9oXHL4LQMlcsACYkSJA2wAfeu8g15b8YcNcHE3SGB8ZJgxjSsDfkBFOy4Rtlz/wBnvaKkNZJgzKAgicEtH5rtiK87+BDo4slyArK6rJnOsAD7GvRrjUrCcaYuRUHFEZqEwqkQDIqDCiRWilUAAihvFHYUu9AAblLvTFygPTAWuUrcpx1pbiWCqWYgKoJJOwAEkmnYCV1aTvJTKdo2Xtm6txe7BI1nCyN8tHWuV7Z+NLSkrYU3n6jCD33P8zScki445Nlq6ZrK884jtvinOo39E/pWYH0xWVH3o2/jyK/gr5W5ptmDOAflJHIzv610Vrird3w3F7u7tn5WOwzy/ma5ZbRS8BEwwMdRO37Ua3c1XwMsrMBE8icj18+tcZ3FrwPHRqUiNRUzP9Lfnwke1dGOPa4nA2GI0W4kCD4lS5ufQ/euKsXZcRLBGHhPQNMfc/Wr/s9AR3ttwWtjUyx4lMmd/mHmOtZygm7LUtUVr8GVCFZKm9sJ5DUsecGPepWjrOoAFnN3EADSoDSOhAJ+lXnY7qLljGpVuy3oCgj7N6Vpuw1uWVu8OIY2nm0NTsZ0qSCc5lsb+IAUPIk9goWU/DXu6bUJ7ucTuDg7DpzHlI5V658AfEa3lFpznltzZFGAM6mckztvsa8ruWpLqRDCRBgDSiLqnHzTMN50S3x3dXFZE7tAApEk+OIfXqnLCZHy5xg1rDJTMsmNTWz6KFlamFrnvhH4iXirUE+McsSRGduhnltHOa6Fb0YIrquzzJRcXTNkeVQa2TR0vCc0cMKV0ISNoxW9FOACoOtFgAt2xRioqAEVIvQBsVhWtK1TJpAYBXjfxLfa2Wum0t241y/qAE6SupgJiSMBa9jivLO1ePtpfui5q7zvHLBS2kS3gEjGRRZriVsV+Crq3+KXVYFvQQwlRmLjAbgQfAD7+lequa857E7RsPxNpQXMuIy/quPOD9POvRGE007FlVMgxoZFEK0NjVGRhahPcrHahGqAixoTLRYrRWgBcpUCtJ8d2/w9l7iXX0G2qsxYYIeYCxljjYVyPbHx47AjhbelY/724DnzW3Emk5UaRxyZ0jdt8LNwd+gNsw8mNJ2jO+RyrkO3/jpHR7fDW+8BDK1x/AgBBBicnFc3xnAMW1XjquMdR1AHfLNoUxj/AFTk7YqfadpUti6FY2yFwQCZzGQfCs9D0rNzdHTHDGypbg2KjvGOgAkbhB6cyT7TRuE4VCCpUyQSAMLHTG+/nV5a4EvZUvqUsgZZ3AIGmJA+woPwpbspZdrjMbneMHkYCgrEPOZz6VjKSX7N0rOZ424UYq6EnrA28hyFZV929x9m7eZlRVG0LJA57+8+9ZUcn6L4r2at2kudpWLWm2sC2jlCSrGM3JO5M+VVfaHYLJf0hkbUruAhkgIzDxD9J8Mx6VDhbhHFC9+nGRk4UDb1FWPYvExxoedrTn3JYn3zWDUo7T8GqcX2c1btsNeJwQTHvP2/NEsXICdSSOcgGuw7LvW7i3FvqWVE4e0unSraf1CY30u2TJpTs34dW8vD6WUFiTBb/MKllVQBpyZM/U+VP7UvyF9d9CvZV1WZtRJQEgnZgxlgYnmRuOldBavd1lXDKQFVkIgAuGMkc9xXKXuyr1sqGRgWugLIhid1IkbEEHpkGi8Bx5QzO5uFiBuFEgFDAImds/SqdSQbR2vFcHa4qSYt3C76WAhSHvooLACWJn6fbm+0ODdWIuABjyOzhiGz/wDkUzMj0o3A9ow8ghc28TNstrV8ncEYME8qvF4lL1rRdX/lMbZOGHgt6WU+ZtsY+9ZrlDrorUlvs5/sTtR+FcMpaJjMiOek+Y5Hy9K9v+Hu2U4q0HGGHzDn61432h2O1s+LxI2zrOlhvpbGG5/fnU/hntm7wd2dQKAiZOc40kEjVz26TXVjyo5M+Hkv2e7BSdqmhO1K9l9pW+Iti5ayDv1B5g08FNdFnn0bUsKKrdaCQa3bU0gCMtDa2aMPSsZqLACBRVFRJFYWpATmvE/iZP8AjeJM/wDOPvXtArxf4lH/ABvE/wDrNnpmoydHT8X8mR+F8cZw5/8AFt/ckfvXs9xhXinYJI4rhj/41n7uBXtjW6MQfL7QsxobCmSlQCVsmcgsUrWmqjtn4r4aytzTcS5dQx3SmWJxOFBMQd9sRXG8T8WcZeBRCtlWZgHgd7kkqARKpAIErqM0+SNI4pM7P4i7YtcNaYvdVHKsLY3YvpOmFyTmOUVwZ+L+NuILQhGJg3NPjM4woOlDgkkx6YpHgOzTce2VVrhul1ZzLEMs/M8kwOkxqERFNDs0dzZa9cVY4jSVXSx7vWVYZgCSATsRqPpWMsyR0ww0VdvhNRZmLXLiiZYlmIHzSeWcDSJMHNbbhblzgW4i0uEBMkEFhq0y+ZJ1BonoKv8AhuJt279+5Ysag6pLkc1UzJaFjxA7E7Zqo7V7QW1bPDtxVtlUERbPeSpzpBOMamXYbVk5yekqN1FLYT4i7HtDghqcO4KmFyGEgt4vfGKl292rbfhnsWreGiDp1R4fCNZAkYO1czxfb6Y0WSxXIa4xOBkGPTzGwqs43ty+/wA1zSP6UECI6j350uK7bsdvwqOm4zirqqq3LyoVUpJOpvCQoydgQCdsRXPP2hw6LEG4x1yTsdR3E7GOYHOqp7DFRczpJIljkkZ/BFb7O4bvX0mRhjjyUkfePrVX6Chi92w7MW7tcnzrKq+IVlYqRBHKspWMueFYDu8ORnUANjyjryqPeuCAIJJ/UM/3q1tqvD8U3DPcS6qPHeJsSRgqdwJMETyonbfDI/Ei3aR2eI0rLEnyG+M/fpWfJNWaU+iu4TtAIHwRqIJ5gkbedWPZXaGg2NLA91AJB2HWDzkDFJW+yjou+IgoVlGGdWoj1xJEda1wnBNcBCgMVJmOQn78/Ok6aBWmdH2T2iR3SsAwN4TqEnHcjE7bHIqCdlcPxFm3B7tzafeSgZiJYtvOrMAcz5VU3bvd24KsLikTIwM4I6cq3wHGNGIMA4B2E6sA+Y5Gs3j8rRop+zO0+w79ksdJZZcaxnogkj8NUOG7RZF8QJ5CZwskiOmSNuu1W9jth0hmJXxMw5b3VLf/AFimA9i+sXUydmtwCCFtj5flI+bHODmhSku1YVF9BOxu2xABOsEQysATHOR+oeYqfafYyujXbPiQfMhyyT/91mPMfeq9/hh51cM4eM6Z0PETs2Cfc0Hh+1L/AA7KHUowAEERMMY1Dmeh3zSVN3F7BppUy5+CPiN+EuhH1G03zc4HX26869j4fj7b4S4pMTggmOv3ryDi7dnjI7sKl5hkAgW7k/07aGxsYB3xvVn8KcVesp4iQ6So1DPofL+wrrxZL0zhz4V+SPVFPnUgKVS+pjImAfrj80DtLtS3YUlzkafD+qGaJjfz9q2OOtlkWgTQOK41EMMYMTsT+K4ztX4pRrKWkZgzKssphlyCsb7wcxtNI9u/E/eJq06WkKQcSAsk5+USw3osuONtl/8ABnbJvPetvrLqSwLDGmYwYjciPKuqIgE9K8h4Dtq6txHWT4l26ahJJ6QY9z0rsfiX4jUC7ZWSpJDMp/T3aTpI2Mkj2NF2OeJpnYqteK/EY/4ziv8A1m984+lenfDPxAl6zNwhXVip84AIbywftXl/bzBuL4kjM3XKn36Vlkejb40akwPY6/8AEcOf/Hs//wBRXuTW68J4NtNy239NxG9dLhor0jifjcrlrQAEzJ+1LEyvkwcmqLL4h+JLHCqdTBrnK0p8Z9cHSPM1572h8ScXxTqFZrY1eBbeGkkqJYDVs4HLr6R0cJam47SXZmCyEGfEBpy7RO4HKkb/AMXKspZQxAgIO7E+EZYhnOw5Cm8jfSFHDGPYez2GFWbjJaUySXjUdVkuCR1DYkwcmnk7m2GfTqhrT67xCLqVQGgNByxJxO9cZxPbHEuRohJ1RpEtiz3sG42o5QCIjc7UC12FfvOC4e5/m2VLGSSt4apBM7D81Et9s2ivRecX8VJ4V70sFZmC2VhQzmfnMCPERIE5qj4j4jb/AJdu2hB0hml3JODBPhnM+9M8D8LvPD94VXVevW31MMhQwBieWeXKoL2NaXhreq7leLcYUnw4U7wDlBnz9qFOK0h8H5KfiuKv3S4d7hZBLAnEBgsBRjBpU8MTw/fKI8bKY5CFKmfc123D3ODTi+KeGdGQQQcSw8XyAkZzNV9liOzmsCxm5+vSdxpOqWOCd8YpW34HpeTnu0OAI4e1dAw2CfPU0e0fmrHtPsZjwNviADpUKrHEZdj68xVl2zxN67YWw0BZUnKKsqTkqoike0+Km0LRu2tIAkSx2JO8jyp1KhXGx3s/sFDwX+ZctjUC4g6vmCwMbNiPKaqPhWxb7u4xLd6AQBA0xHWZnf7Vpu0baoEHENABA0qI5RsCdp51XjjLKiArsSDMkgGYgx5Z+tCi/LG5LwjXbXDTdJ6/3NZQm4y1M91v6VlUSL9jMoupqaBOT0BEU5f7Tu2OLN+xdKuDKOImIjY8j0IqHw5wge4Cf6lGPM0PtXgiL1yNgx9d4qHXkpXRZWe0Ll1OIuO+u6wJJPzszEZEek4p3sft03Bw3DCxaQoWBuqIuXQQTDnYgQKX4PsZlt8QGRg4A8PMeIAjHPNVfYHCd5xCryn96jjFmltHQ8F2xZdNBS5/imdlZyw7s248IC/1AgfSicPxHCtbB1am03TctlCBa0HwMrg+LUDONtq5fsq2z8Qo1GdcTz3irPsjhmNu9cbB7tiNsypJMctqThXkalZ0HHdnWRaDJxFsjJV9RUOECllQETrzGnEnM9Uuzez2e5eCZ7sPIJiE1jx4PnyzmoXeyWNi0ofZ26YJK7Y/kCgcBwzG8SzZDXcxvC6T/wDapjddlNbui3tcJxSagyPMsGlcCIkE4255O46iW7Hb+ldF62GWGlWyPFCmJAIMgbGcVRdjPeXxC4ywkgSYzaZtp8l91B5U9xnavENqR2VlX5dSgnwXJG+/yjHMfdOLfaC0uh+3wnDXWDcPcNgndXlrRIx83zLkbEH1FXXAK6oyuQWBEkEEbHYjeub4ftCQEfhbR+YErrQnlJ0mJx0pyxDqFDJbGqe7Ys5xMSQAWA3g+VVjfB2+iJx5qkXr9rXL6oHuNyGkRpJDjLDTvL+eM1Vcffc6dJJJAIJmciRgARvTF+2LMaQzSFMgOZYhSzgacLKyAesZqlv963J1UWwI0MAToiAI1DpvyrrjNSWjk+vi9kl419IZyugY5gE8pMdeVA7aLMqa2AQmRuWOBEYGoR6RNVtvgmFph3b4cHToaTAIxiM9fSp9oaxZtKEMqGz4sTy0kY3qUjW0XHYqollizgoCzLhhy+V5EKC0cjvTzXbAIYXGhiNB2/SDIxk7DlXLG+e4CFfmdcEmDHMr0n8UvduKDpZCdJbb5cnkDMDFAqOsdmRmIgiRMwCARkkMD0I3qPA3QRdJ/Vq6b6gR771Q3O0SseFiXWWOqZkQAcYIA2zWz2mbYXE6hqwdtW6nG9Ke0VCNN2W7kcsbe3nTfEcKnc201TobdgCYkk/tXLt2yT/yzHry+nrWk7VsEQ1hlGqfAd55MTUQVDnujseF7H4ZBLOchmPhCiT8oliBEyZig3OP4Gy2FtkjSRqulvla2QP8sHP+Wf8A5etc3aFh2AXh3WW3YwNpgmcDG9D7T7MJgIF5CVLE4IHMxnV05etKvYF8fii2mkWyi6VEabLHaybQy0GCGP0HWlOJ+Kp/VdYTbME21/7pdKcjBEbiKo34RyJFpBqnZTgaA+JJ6Ee7DnUH4S5IGhRLKDCD/mjbb6dOUUUvQV+xp+3xytTGombjkSZltIxOTkRvS1ztt10kIiEbHu/Fn9QZt56043a3Ev4fCBeT/DMFtAf5VsQqjGDmSRmRSfaXanEXQtxySUDWQ2lR4dMadogB4653nNVbFSMudqcX3feargts2nUqgKzf0zEzjlQe1LXFWnCX1uq7AEKSdTTjEHJJjHmKavcfej/Dl27uye9FsjwAhwQYA1bkznpSXa/al/iT311izScjZdsL0A8MCi2FCY4S49wWxbY3S2gIZ165jTBGDPWhhSzhVUAswUL/AKidMSfPrWcQh0AkEyWyefiPPnWPw8WlaD4geXmRv7UDIcRaZGZWwyMVYYIDKYIkYORuK3xXCMmjUVPeILi6WDQrEwGj5WxscjFZa4ebRb/VH2B/ehcFb1OB5H7CmIGHitVjjNZQIvfhb5h/6ifmodqXpv3RA+dh/wDtQuzC1ogkhcg5I5eta4hlZ2bvEy04BJyZ2AqGWjp+AuRbvmTOiZ2z3gn96pfhkqOKmcArvj9YmpLxCwxlxqG+kiQc/wAND4KyAxKKTH6mY9egA/NSqRbt6NfDxVeLJbADmD6XKf4G7CuhUnXbuQQCRIVgAYzkkVvs/gyZYhAeULlj/wCYzFWNjgCUgyTO8tt6bfwVnPNFFwwyaMtcT/loWOkqSSrFVLyBAXVkRE0vwNwux0gHSbjGAzmHbE6Bj1q/t8MipCoikrBIAk88wJNA7J4YIW5z1nf13rn/AJKptI3fx+rYHheyHIIJacGYRIhdIGC3LyqwTsTUSdREkY1ah7YXz5czTtljuI/+P8mmFbpPqZ/nLyrnfyMjfo0+mCRXWeyeIW4YWy1onBcMWjzEkfarVey7RdiUGYkCdPSAvTypxLowNzz3/c1BbktXofGbltnB8j+vQ6ttV+VAMAY3xtOf5NRuQelRe96etCd69BLR50rbCQKDftjmK13np5ef8/eh37vKCQN9sfU0CN8PaWf4aZe2OlJ2roB6g7Hb+GmHbmDt5iRQGzdxgByFcl2ifEc/mupdwQcg494zXJdokajDDl5e07Gom6Rth7GOzLSyJAPsOsV0YtoRGlfpXM9mXIIEGf7n8CZroxc943gjHvRFJxDJfINcsppjSAPQVX8VwdtvmUH/AGpy7d8NJ3LmD/t+9cUonZBsQvcDb/pHv/t9KWudnW94gzOMZ9qYu3YOYBPLmfShNxAIJGr6R7gZxUPRrF2JNwKjbcDGTg9R50tc4JZGSBEwGO/Xf0prv5BIMxvFLXbgkDnz9ZiB158+VO2Ghb/CNJIuPLYOeUzt61rjuFwttHYIcsPCZJwSP96Ml0EEnGmPXO0ifrnatcfdOoBQYPM4O+xk+E+R5RtT5NsSiqKriOHZotT4BsNK9ZPKJkmhXVZtNoHwqYWVEwWnYYnNHu3yXgZOfz/DNDtXD3gBjJjAmZwNs8x9a0tkUmxbilZUNlSI1TiBkiCfWhWma0wcKgJUjAP9MEiev7mj8dcIcjAImd/ofPl6igcb8qH/AEiQRG+ZHUedUpPQnFbErgZjOkcvLYRWURduZ9DWVVk8SNiyhCwc/qnYdIxP5o9i2dU6cTByBE55+ho964htWtKqrBCrAMxYkPOtgQAs5hZO4NQ7N0m4pgnSQ0EBgYIwwONPnn06Teil2OcRa0yBBjMyCI6Y3NMcEwICidRPIH9h5z5e9JcZe1sx0hOenAgCBBGB5YA9KJ3hVIBaGI3wIUYg6s75xyFZtWjRSpsurXEDQrBTLFtKhWJMGCVxH06UyOIzpYlTMEEQFnmfLPLoaq2OhA3kdQkTnYMf1TgzGJovDcUE0ydQEDOpfDA6iQNUEFc4zE1hLGmarI0Wl+8FEkyskBhB25g71LgeJA2BH75jzj3qu4jii8YMEaoXVmJgkmZgdeQzUuzXJBMYGxyQM525kasRy51n9a4l/Y2y+tcUJ5nMTqkfYUzauidiTyz+PTP3qhRyCFGrMzqLbYJkzPTYc6MupDJJMbgT8voeedjuDz5JYhSyNnUWbkgAggecCPqM1osNXhyRv5dOVVVq4VglhtkFYM8yOY9DtRbPEBm358iIH0M16Hx4NbPPzystoPT7fvWmmQG265/6GlHuj1iOUxUGug7/AHxnzFdiRxPsf4gcgCRH29hS3EahnTI8tJ0/g/SlrnEf+X7Y+2aD3kicHyCyD6yMUUMLwaNJbeT/AFHb3OKdu43g55En8VVpcG5x6Hf2G3tTWoRJke8fcTNFAx+wTpJOPcEn0AG9cT2qD3hJ0j3Mn1kA/aumcApJDOBJiZ25AGJrku0bQnWGaMDTckXI65ksvnWeTo1w9jPZgYEEMInGd/L6+VdilwMsmAYyQcA+kZrg+z3PeKBME5+Xb/3beddkiMqjwzA6wI32INGNaHm7QR2AXcH0z+Nh/ek3uDmxHt+SYrXENiYkev4xA2oGs7gE+mfyN551nKGyozBXSATkeu2/23jaKFK5CmcYO/nBnAn9qm9g76CekJtsemRIpaIPjGkdCNvfTG09azlA2hO2AfTMeIYIG0DmIPTfcchQ2uQNRBwCJ1DPQEaeWrepNfAP6ZwJGkyJEjMGfaaBxLqSYG0ZiQfKBtvyqOFl8qNIVJ06Zg9YjxeXp9Kj2iyEpzPiMsQNUQNyfIbx5TWSLcOCBG0agcdA25rXaTamJdmDQAYCtpLQQCccgeR2ik1spPRX6wMaQcdTjbPntyz+KziFA8cKAWzb1eIZHPkNoxFD4lN4KzA+bB26Z9fQc60bmZBK6cDJhZO0mY5n3qqJsDdugkQqYk7bkZgycmtcX8skASSRsSZyRvGPIbz6CbXCVCKfD0O0ndiYxy8qBfkGDDECJ3weQB235UwYmCeX7VupEKcmfpP5rKsk3eu6s5bYAmZMDmeZpjs9j3gAE8z4iCVG6gSNRyCBPKluJvkknUTqOoyQZaMtjnv9anYktOBpAcxIMKQDDZYHn5E+QFLwNPZJiS3i1TMZEHEAT58qct8TpUiSpKgZUGZMwByjeaVa6XLszSJmGYksZwMkMcE+KiJfIBGloIXJBLAAzKE/KDEbH5alopMsWvqAG1KupIIXWAGUTqfEEsJ8I5nYRUFtodHjtzDFlBaFHLxRpAxyJ3NKpsFLakBOTPdqYkS0eJoBHTaKLw110UNMEAjBHykSRkHeRkdTtvUUVZYAwdJeB+qJMEnbMdBvtp6CprfkfKGz4TBMLBnE4gGcgcqRe9DkP4VKACAMDDKROD68wTUrTKBOtcSo1MMiN18IgSTmZ3xsaXEfKi0t3ZhQBGCYfcZwAvLy3xR+FfGPHqzKqQMESDBk75Mc/pV8OQI8OtRtp0nlGRO/mas0ZwYZTb5jVE74kTjHl9YrWEDKcixtXwuCd+Ux+Yn3qauxPhQ+Zk7exz9Kri4BnBJg7KeXmaaW+B+tfZR/auvHHRyTex72J8iD+9b71hsrdIAwBzJzJPliq48byBEehH9qkl//AFAecEz9TWlGVDr3TOx+0/cmKi9wzi2389CBQG1nIk+eiB9Yith2HNfciaKANYBnz9Rn2U1O86zJGfKlLdzrB/nlRLmenuT+NqdDoO14aYliPIfvGa5PtGyVuNJMEyCRBI9AI8q6NGcfK6jzEfg1R9qWbasoMknLOSTieX6ftWOVaNMWmB4C8QfAhZ+QkwROZAI+ma6u3xAIHhUEbiSM9BI/auMXiQjBraxBnc59RIro+H4rvEDEBSeUEH7jajF6HlQ61+MDBO0HE75oNy85G/rk5HnM0IY5L7/9KC753Ht+a0cTJURe7OMEnlKT9IqRJA0k6JzjSOXUQQJ+4oZujYwT6RyobOBEac7yCccoMfms3FPs1Ta6MvWDMiIMyV3jpmfzS620kQi9YnPKcidJgRG+fSid6NUAsG5wOh6kVq6WGdKtGehPmeRxGINZvH5Rop+GL8TYB2UgbBSAdIjlgmPcHyNL92sEHGkiAJ5DACnPU8hRhdHyhCIOrEcgTpnkDO3WoC2cnSwwY8UmdOJkHmZIx0rNr9GsWKPBmGJOTDCCPcH+ZpXDbj7gcvPb0o3ELBgRJnfw+55e80F7NwQSCQBHhGYB8vWigs00AHHPAmduc8xvQNMEFRynAmIz54B60a4ox4o8mB9ckUJxyV1iSYmOWaKCxdrk7ov35Ynfc71lRuODvExyUVugCIDLBI9JyTzmDmPPapOR4tieo+USQfDGxn2yahZuiSQAMewkEdZMn2zU1KsZ0wD82YWTMQFGBPKDtQAxwwOrWLXeBBLKFhR/SWiQRMY57edNW7Z0XZFsAQSjMAQc4VdyQSRp8xjFV1hCW06iskDMxviY+tO3xbVvF45j5ZVgQQDq1LnVBPlOczUspE7fENoOjCEwdQPiZobl4caMYBiipxJCw0HUgGFyBGpcQAJ1DOT50h3zEsEgA50qflC+Ib9PrvRrDTLXS5Mjmsmctlgc7EHz86TQ7GFViFaARAnElYJUAxsDvHP2ondtgQpVf9S5zufFEZ5jnSlhwrNjWOR+Ue4px7YJgQFxlRPi3MmeXP29mkhNssrKQZMNtjwwPLA2xttU++1kgN4iZwANt42HrvvS/C21UtBLMwGqc6hgiQZ5waJafT4QsD0x65rpUV6OdyfseQsIlfr/AGmp/wCJjk30FKi70cff+1b0Mf1E+ZECtv8ADKr7GP8AFHYK8+i/2FES6wMwZ84kfTalNTjZh+a2UY/M4pWFIae/cJkn7z+Sa2bh5x9P96T0AfrH0NRZCf1z60WFDqXuQk/Sm7Cggl2CxsIkn0O1U9u20YYAfzrU46n8UBQ6X/1Ae81R8fb/AMwRcLE7apx1HSKeuOoBYwAB5Zqk4niWYzsRtH+1Z5Gi4Ldlp2dbZWyVg7iM+x5U+14f0H61z3AX2NwAsYPIkwfWaubjeUe5/vVY2q0Ka3sN3k/paoFuooNxuTGKEfI1bJoZZ56D+bZmsL+ft/OdLhj5VHvPKloAt3xDbHQ/zBoIQjYH01tH3qYcdKHcfOGjyxP3pMaCcJxsE6rRYdH1wYIMKyEEExE0lcvZBLHMjRMECdzIiemaOcZlj5b/APSlbnEggSp3iIwPc71jKNO7NYu10Qa0+4EiCPEwbf1+s0J0KiNLeUE+cyRyiK3cUiNKkehGP70Es42Lfb+9TS7KTItcDEKVccvmMe8/k0s88hHrj/rvtR7zXY/tFAF9yYkD1wKTGhcNPL7VlFJb+lf571uigsDw8iSDkBpkgYjMScncRvtUbQZyqjJMKNh5ASce5odohm8bEAnxNGo+ZifEfeiuwAxG8ebRkMRsBygHlSGO8dwrodL237yNRbvA40gxPhBiIidVL21zMTiT9c9fxQbV1lkqSurwmMSD+k9RjbbFGs8Uyg/6gAGzIiMiD5bbUqY7QxduXWFsZ0/pACxnaIE7Dn0mi8Pf1QfCTiZ6AYIJbJicQIpC64iBMdT571IOTAAUbAmBJycknnnlGwoSoLsa4niFMhRBJ5TkYgkAxnpnaneDXQMkDPPP3xmgcOViNPIfpAEgfn+9Htid0AwYmCwblO8j+TVR7sT6C/4oEwpn/wAqk/U7U2sbEz59ftP2FLq0CJ/H4FSDjzNbIyYx/l9T/PasZk5En2NKLfjGma2HmnyFQwr1LV/M/wB6X1D+TW1uDqaLCg8mtgUI3POjcXwbIFOu2wYbo4MHoRuDQBtUHMxW3sgZ1CKTMc4rQvL/AEzRYUGuMsbgg/zelFtIM6o/9wxTI4wRGkRSd62h2XT7yPpUSKiHtgSp1FiM7/fyphL2oSDSFrh15yftTa3FAAAgCnFikgmk9a3qPWhG+K13oJGKqyaC951itd5QS46VhuLTsKDE+dDdtsT9MfWhaR1qLAedJsaRO7dwcE+lDW4OfhJ5SD/N6gVqLqCMianZWjd23nDEem30pZiQYLqfUQa2wHKR6E0G4gJnn51LGiT3N/Ep+tJ3gu8wfLNMaB0AoLIvSpYweodBWql3S+f1rKQxdkKkhhnp6iRROHRnwOQLeyiT+9ZWUg8m0vxgQJBBJzM7zjascYBgdMT0/NZWUUFm7t2TMgnfCgZPpUUYjNZWUwLKxecgEKD1JMc/KmkJ/UB7E1lZVRJYYECsDitVlWIzWKJb0859v96yspCJa186gb45D71lZRY0jXeGsRutZWUxBAy9JrTRGMfet1lFgDSCJrZArKyhDA8Q5UAgDzo1ohgCJzWVlJdg+iLqazTWqymIlpqLaaysoA1jrWmMbZ/nnWVlDAiWoTPWVlKygZegOG5H2rVZUsEBuXT5elDuXj1/uK1WVFlUaQE8z/Pat1lZQB//2Q==">
```

Но никакого эфекта в mozila

Comment: `filter: blur(5px)` очевидно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
img:hover
{
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
     -moz-filter: blur(5px);
       -o-filter: blur(5px);
      -ms-filter: blur(5px);
          filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Подробнее о [filter:blur()](https://webref.ru/css/value/blur).

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px
}

img:hover {
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg" />
```